# RNA-seq analysis - q-values in cuffdiff

Tags: bioinformatics, statistics, rna-sequencing

I'm using cuffdiff 2.1.1 to look for differential gene expression between two conditions. Each condition has 2 biological replicates. The results I get look promising from a log fold change perspective - lots of genes that I would expect to be affected have the highest fold change values. However, from a q-value perspective very few of the results look promising, having q values > 0.05.

My question is, given 2 replicates, how is the q value calculated? Surely if there was high variance between replicates but the difference between experimental conditions was also large then the q-values would be correspondingly high?

In this case, can I, or should I, really trust the q-values?

Comment: http://cufflinks.cbcb.umd.edu/manual.html#gene_exp_diff

Comment: If after a few days you don't get good answers here, consider reasking the question here:

http://www.biostars.org/

It's basically stackexchange specifically for bioinformatics.  About a third of the questions over there are about next generation sequencing.

Answer (score 3):

q-value is the corrected p-value to account for multiple testing (i.e. you are testing thousands of genes). Those with q-value <0.05 are significant experiment-wise. Cuffdiff uses Benjamini-Hochberg correction to compute FDR (i.e. q-value). The calculation does not depend on the number of replicates it's based on the distribution of p-values those, yes, are influenced by the number of replicates. The more replicates you have the better).